# How to use 'would' to express vagueness

Tags: word-usage, modality

I have been told that modal 'would' can be used to express 'vagueness'. Its usage has been linked below but I'm not fully convinced yet with it because I don't know in what kind of context it would be approprite to use 'would' for 'vagueness'. Does 'would' carries any kind of meanings while using it in those contexts? Is it formal or natural to use?

> 14. **modal verb**
>       You use *would*, or sometimes *would have* with a past participle, when you are expressing your opinion about something or seeing if people agree with you, especially when you are uncertain about what you are saying.
>
> [vagueness]
>   ⇒ I think you'd agree he's a very respected columnist.
>   ⇒ I would have thought it a proper job for the Army to fight rebellion.
>   ⇒ 'Was it much different for you when you started at the Foreign Office?'—'Worse, I'd expect.'.
>   ⇒ I would imagine she's quite lonely living on her own.